# MySQL Group By & WHERE Clause

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL Table where i stored some information regarding a `server_id`.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT server_id,COUNT(*) as online_clients
FROM `user_activity` 
WHERE ISNULL(`date_end`) 
GROUP BY `server_id`;
```

from which I expected to return all rows of unique `server_id` and the `online_clients` for each one of it.

However if i remove the WHERE Clause ** I get all the server_ids** and the **online_clients** for each one of them.

Why with the WHERE clause that doesnt work? ***Shouldn't i get all the server_ids again with their online_clients witch is zero (0) in this example?*** (Since there is no null in date_end).

Thank you

Comment: may be you can try as `group by server_id having date_end is NULL` by removing the where clause

Comment: that didn't work. It says date_end is unknown column on having  clause

Comment: make it a part of select statement i.e. `date_end`

Comment: yes i tried. The query executed but again 0 rows returned... what is happening...

Comment: Could you add some data and the table in http://sqlfiddle.com and the expected output in to the question ? Looks like the date data is saved as `0000-00-00` which is not null

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/527c3/2

And still, shouldn't i get both rows? I only get the server_id 1. The server id 2 should have been printed with online_clients 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q:** Why with the WHERE clause that doesn't work? Shouldn't i get all the server_ids again with their online_clients witch is zero (0) in this example?

**A:** The predicate in the WHERE clause will filter out rows, if there are no rows with NULL value in `date_end` column, the query won't return any rows. And we wouldn't expect any rows to be returned.

If we wanted to return a distinct list of `server_id` from the table, along with count of "online_clients", we could use a query like this:

```
SELECT a.server_id
     , SUM(ISNULL(a.date_end)) AS online_clients
  FROM `user_activity` a 
 GROUP BY a.server_id
```

Comment: Thank you boss. Oh man you are right. I feel so dumb :D Thank you